# Merge two Audio files FFMpeg acodec

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I am trying to merge two audio files using ffmpeg for Android. The problem is, acodec of the output file is ac3, so it wont work on Android phones unless I install VLC for Android. I tried the output on VLC for Android it works great.
Here's the command I am using.

`-i audio1.avi -i audio2.avi -filter_complex     amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 audioMerged.avi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.avi -i audio2.avi \
-filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 \
-c:a libmp3lame audioMerged.avi
```

Or better yet,

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.avi -i audio2.avi \
-filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 \
-c:a aac -strict -2 audioMerged.mp4
```

For output to WAV (this will be uncompressed files)

```
ffmpeg -i audio1.avi -i audio2.avi \
-filter_complex amix=inputs=2:duration=first:dropout_transition=3 \
-c:a pcm_s16le -vn -dn -sn -strict -2 audioMerged.wav
```

Comment: Hi yes thank you the both solutions worked, but as I am executing these commands on Android phone, now it takes longer than before. Before the execution time of 1 min of audio was like 5 seconds and now its 35-40 seconds. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have space for WAV? 1 minute will be 5 to 12 MB depending on sampling rate and no. of channels?

Comment: yes I can do that. What if I tell you a few commands and you can change them and codec should be WAV? I am new to ffmpeg. :/

Comment: I got this output now by trying 3rd command 
`Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid data found when processing input`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105007/discussion-between-noman-rafique-and-mulvya).